# R -- Extract string/s from a json output based on criteria

Tags: python, r, dplyr

I am trying to extract certain values from a json output after using google API. Out of the entire output, I wish to extract specific values based on defined criteria. The table I'm working with looks like this-

| index | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {'city_display_city_name_fg': True, 'subMarket_id': 1631, 'subMarket_tx': 'Southern NH', 'market_id': 644, 'market_tx': 'Southern NH', 'metro_id': 37} |
| 2 | {'city_display_city_name_fg': False, 'subMarket_id': 2464, 'subMarket_tx': 'north NH', 'market_id': 541, 'metro_id': 57} |

I would like my mutate new columns with the resulting table to be:

| index | value | market_id | market_tx | metro_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | {'city_display_city_name_fg': True, 'subMarket_id': 1631, 'subMarket_tx': 'Southern NH', 'market_id': 644, 'market_tx': 'Southern NH', 'metro_id': 37} | 1631 | Southern NH | 37 |
| 2 | {'city_display_city_name_fg': False, 'subMarket_id': 2464, 'subMarket_tx': 'north NH', 'market_id': 541, 'metro_id': 57} | 541 |  | 57 |

Using R(preferred) or Python, what is a good way of parsing the value column and extracting these values?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks! Most of my results have been using excel using the  `TRIM`  and  `MID`functions, which isn't giving me the results I want.

Comment: There are several packages in R to convert JSON into a data frame.  For example "jsonlite" is a popular packages

Comment: @Dave2e what if it's just all characters instead of json? Whats a good way of string extraction in this specific way

Answer (score 1):

This is a feasible solution using Python.

##### Logic:

- convert your **API output** into a plain df with `pd.Dataframe()`
- split "**value**" column into separate columns with `apply(pd.Series)`
- merge splitted columns with previous  df  with  `concat()`
- drop useless columns with `drop()`

##### Code:

```
  import pandas as pd
    
  api_output = {'index':[1,2] ,
                'value': [{'city_display_city_name_fg': True, 'subMarket_id': 1631, 'subMarket_tx': 'Southern NH', 'market_id': 644, 'market_tx': 'Southern NH', 'metro_id': 37}, {'city_display_city_name_fg': False, 'subMarket_id': 2464, 'subMarket_tx': 'north NH', 'market_id': 541, 'metro_id': 57}]}
    
  # convert entire API output into pandas df
  api_df = pd.DataFrame(api_output)
    
  # split "value" to columns, concat with previous api_df, drop useless columns
  final_df = pd.concat([api_df, api_df['value'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1).drop(['city_display_city_name_fg','subMarket_id','subMarket_tx'], axis=1)
```

##### Result:

| index | value | market_id | market_tx | metro_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | {'city_display_city_name_fg': True, 'subMarket_id': 1631, 'subMarket_tx': 'Southern NH', 'market_id': 644, 'market_tx': 'Southern NH', 'metro_id': 37} | 644 | Southern NH | 37 |
| 2 | {'city_display_city_name_fg': False, 'subMarket_id': 2464, 'subMarket_tx': 'north NH', 'market_id': 541, 'metro_id': 57} | 541 | NaN | 57 |

Answer (score 0):

You can extract all the values from the string and keep only the columns that you need.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(value = gsub('[{}]', '', value)) %>%
  separate_rows(value, sep = ',\\s*') %>%
  separate(value, c('name', 'value'), sep = ':\\s*') %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)

#  index city_display_city_name_fg subMarket_id subMarket_tx market_id market_tx   metro_id
#  <int> <chr>                     <chr>        <chr>        <chr>     <chr>       <chr>   
#1     1 True                      1631         Southern NH  644       Southern NH 37      
#2     2 False                     2464         north NH     541       NA          57
```

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in reproducible format.

```
df <- structure(list(index = 1:2, value = c("{city_display_city_name_fg: True, subMarket_id: 1631, subMarket_tx: Southern NH, market_id: 644, market_tx: Southern NH, metro_id: 37}", 
"{city_display_city_name_fg: False, subMarket_id: 2464, subMarket_tx: north NH, market_id: 541, metro_id: 57}"
)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```